# What does it mean "Don't go ...ing something"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

Could anybody help me to understand a line from "Lay All Your Love On Me" by [ABBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABBA)?

> I wasn't jealous before we met
>   Now every woman I see is a potential threat
>   And I'm possessive, it isn't nice
>   You've heard me saying that smoking was my only vice
>   But now it isn't true
>   Now everything is new
>   And all I've learned has overturned
>   I beg of you
>
> **Don't go wasting your emotion**
>   Lay all your love on me
>
> (LyricFind)

What the difference with "Don't waste your emotion"?

Comment: What is "ABBA"?

Answer (score 2):

ABBA (written thus) was a Swedish pop music group in the 1970s, famous world-wide. "Don't go [doing something]" is an idiomatic way of strongly suggesting that the listener does not do something. "Don't go wasting your emotion" is equivalent to "Don't waste your emotion".